# What will be called next after the mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this situation which I don't know what is been called after the mapStateToProps function called by Redux.

so the main question is what will be called next after the mapStateToProps functions OR when can I access my props ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` update the props for the component and hence `componentWillReceiveProps` is the function that will receive the updated props and this is where you can perform the check and take necessary action

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps['yourMontoringProps'] !== this.props['yourMontoringProps']) {
        console.log(nextProps) // take action here based on nextProps;  
    }
}
```

**P.S.** The initial props passed to the component by mapStateToProps are available in the `componentDidMount/componentWillMount/constructor` function and hence you could use these to take initial actions. `componentDidMount` is a suggested place to do it though

Comment: It's not really. because I don't change state in reducer.

Comment: connect is pure and hence if nothing changes for the component, the component won't be re-rendered. So if mapStateToProps has updated something, it will be available to componentWillReceiveProps(not with this.props but with nextProps)

Comment: as I said. its mapStateToProps. its just reading the data from the store and nothing else. nothing is gonna change in store.

Comment: @M.R.Safari, `console.log(nextProps)` in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and you should see the desired values there